# Calculating an array's number of elements... Able to refer to its index values by just stating the return type? What? How? Why? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I am learning how to calculate the size and number of elements in an array and came across a question. In a tutorial I see
we can calculate the number of elements in an array as follows ...

```
int array_variable [] = {1, 5, 8, 10};

int array_variable_number_of_elements = sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof (int);
```

I am aware and fully understand why you could replace

```
sizeof (int);
```

with

```
sizeof (array_variable[0]); // or use any index value from the array_variable
```

The video appears to suggest using just int is good practice which I don't understand. The computer obviously isn't psychic and int is simply a data type. What happens when there are two int type arrays in the same function? Why does this work? Does this work because it is in the same line as the following?

```
int array_variable_number_of_elements = sizeof(array_variable)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Why would it matter whether there's another int array in the same function?

Comment: I am not sure if it would but I assume, perhaps incorrectly it would? I just don't understand why using int alone works as it is not a variable.

Comment: using int alone ***doesn't*** work. Read the code properly. The number of ints in the array, is the number of bytes in the array, divided by the number of bytes in an int.

Comment: Thank you very much :) This helps understand things more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second approach is better and more generic, when you need to change the type of array `int` to `char`, you don't have to edit second line at all.

```
  char array_variable [] = {'a', 'b', 'c' }; //changed this line only
    
  int array_variable_number_of_elements = sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof 
  (array_variable[0]);
```

To answer your below comment;

above lines you can interpret like below;

```
  int array_variable = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    
  int array_variable_number_of_elements = sizeof(array_variable) / sizeof ( int);
 //              ^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^                 ^^^
//  array_variable_number_of_elements =       20     /     4 ; // 20 / 4 = 5
```

total array `size` in bytes 20 and size of `int` is 4 bytes in my system;
total number of elements in array is 5;

Comment: Thanks very much this does make sense. I just don't understand how simply using int still works though :p Ok so perhaps a light bulb just went off in my head, does this work because a single int has a value of 4 bytes no matter the context?

Comment: sizeof operator gives size of the object or type, it's depend on the computer architecture,`int` in most architectures is 4 bytes. more [details](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) are hear on fundamental types

Comment: Thank you very much! This makes absolute sense now, I just didn't know how int by itself was calculating an accurate number in this context. I agree with you and Bathsheba that hard-coding in less places makes editing down the road smoother and easier and intended to do it without using just int. Just baffled me why int worked, glad I was able to figure it out with everyone's help. Thanks!

Comment: `int` is 32 bits of width or 4 bytes on 32/64 bit systems as per above mentioned doc

Comment: Thanks again very much, appreciate the specificity :) PS I edited your post not because of anything you did but because I updated the code I listed because terms weren't defined as clearly as they should have been by me :) ...  Well I can't edit it at moment but if eventually can just wanted to let you know.